# every SSL certificate fails in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I have downgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 7 today. Now EVERY time i call ANY https:// url in chrome, it tells me that the connection is not secure. My time settings are correct and the sites work fine in every other browser. I have tried emptying the cache and reinstalling chrome to no avail.

What could be the issue? I cannot find ANY information on this at all - nobody seems to have had this problem before?

EDIT: I want to emphasize that NO site/url with https works. This is not restricted to a specific website. I cannot even call google via https (which seems to be the default with HTST). Changing the url to http:// then works.

EDIT2: the problem persists in chromium and all chromium-based browsers that I could muster the time and nerve installing.

Comment: Try following this tutorial on deleting your Chrome profile: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vE0K9wPvfYo - this should reset any custom Chrome settings that may have gone a bit awry during your downgrade :)

Comment: Thank you, but this did not solve the problem. I've uninstalled Chrome, deleted the UserData and reinstalled -> Chrome fails to connect to the user account login on the very first start (not secure https)

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was that the license for my Bitdefender Antivirus did not "survive" the downgrade to Win 7 - after reinstalling and restoring the license everything worked again.